# excel array error - shows for some users not others

Tags: arrays, excel

may be a simple question, but i'm baffled and cannot find answers anywhere! I have an excel workbook that i have created that has multiple tables, charts and pivot tables.
i have one column which grabs content from another table (via formula:=Table1[Test Results]), works fine on my computer. but when another user opens it on their computer it is showing as an array formula with curly brackets {=Table1[Test Results]} and isn't pulling correctly which in turn is affecting the pivot tables attached to the column.

upon research, their version of excel is the same as mine. and this affects multiple columns. also, when i use the "find & select > go to special > current array" function on my computer, a popup saying "no cells were found" appears.

please help, thank you

Comment: Then their version does not have the dynamic array functionality.

Comment: thank you! do you happen to know a work-around? or an alternate formula i can use?